# How to find flink recovery time metrics?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have a flink job which contains pretty big state. So the recovery time seems very long. We are tuning the system to find its bottleneck. We want to know the recovery time of the job. But there seems no metrics to have this recovery time. How can I estimate the recovery time?

Comment: Have you looked at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/monitoring/metrics.html#availability ?

Comment: Yes, I have checked that. Those metrics seem to be measuring the living job. There seems not metrics measuring the recovering time for a newly starting job.